# "selected" in drop down menu using php

Tags: php

```
$options1 = array( 1=>'= Equals', '≠ Does not Equal', '> Is greater than', '≥ Is greater than or equal to', '< Is less than', '≤ Is less than or equal', '∋ Contains', '∌ Does not contain');

<select name="entry_id_selector[]">';
foreach ( $options1 as $i1=>$opt1 ) : 
echo '<option value="' .$i1 .'"'
.($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic) .'? "selected" : "">'
.$opt1 .'</option>';
endforeach;
echo '</select>';

$entry_id_selector_topic = $_POST['entry_id_selector'];
```

What is wrong with this part of code `.($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic) .'? "selected" : ""`

Default value is `= Equals`

For example, user select `> Is greater than` then click on Post button, page reloads. I expect that in drop down menu is selected and displayed value `> Is greater than` hovewer selected is default value.

Changed to this `.($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic) .'? selected="selected" : "">'` Get always selected last item from array `∌ Does not contain`

Update. Finally get solution. At first did not understand why `$entry_id_selector_topic[0]`
 does not allways displays the first item from `$options1`.

But when I choose some value from drop down menu and click submit button, `$entry_id_selector_topic = $_POST['entry_id_selector'];` the only value that exists is the value I chose from drop down menu. So in `$entry_id_selector_topic` there is new array with the only item [0].

Seems now the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works

```
echo '<td><select name="entry_id_selector[]" onmousedown="SetWidthToAuto(this)">';
foreach ( $options1 as $i1=>$opt1 ) : 
echo '<option value="' .$i1 .'"'
.(($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic[0])? 'selected' : "") .'>'
.$opt1 .'</option>';
endforeach;
echo '</select></td>';
```

Only I have no explanations regarding `$entry_id_selector_topic[0]`

Answer (score 1):

i think that it should be:

```
($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic)?"selected" : ""
```

if that condition is true it will return "selected" otherwise it will return "" .

Comment: Tried such code `echo '<option value="' .$i1 .'"' .($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic)? "selected" : ""> .$opt1 .'</option>';` Displays nothing (get blank page). Seems I placed `'` in wrong place..

Answer (score 1):

```
  echo '<option value="'.($i1 == $entry_id_selector_topic) ? "selected" : "".'>'.$opt1 .'</option>';
```

try this

Comment: Does not display `$opt1`. When click opens blank drop down menu (menu without values)

Comment: try the functionality isset()

Comment: only question is why `$entry_id_selector_topic[0]
` does not always displays first item in array?

Comment: $entry_id_selector_topic[0]-- it has only the selected value